Edit the characters in one file based on the characters of another file
I have an .ind file that looks like this:
    I001.HO M Ignore_Iran_Zoroastrian_PCA_outlier.HO
    I002.HO M Ignore_Iran_Zoroastrian_PCA_outlier.HO
    IREJ-T006.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T009.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T022.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T023.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T026.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T027.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T037.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T040.HO M Iran_Fars.HO

And am trying to subset it to only certain individuals. So I have a list of my required individuals in a .txt file that looks like this:
   IREJ-T026.HO 
   IREJ-T027.HO
   IREJ-T037.HO
   IREJ-T040.HO

However the eigensoft subset with convertf only takes the population name not the individual name. Which as you can see individuals from the same population have the same population name (Iran_Fars.HO).
How can I go through the first file and look for only lines with the individuals listed in the second file and then append like "_B" to the end of the population name so those individuals in the list have a different population name than the others?
Thanks in advance!
I have been trying to use awk or sed in some way but I am a novice and I cannot figure it out

In your .txt file is IREJ-T026.HO IREJ-T027.HO IREJ-T037.HO IREJ-T040.HO all on one line or on separate lines?

separate lines, sorry the formatting did not work. so the file is one column, each row one individual name

No worries, that makes it a little easier.

I'm not sure what the _B stuff is about, but grep -F -f second_file first_file will find all the lines in the first file that match any lines in the second file.

please update the question with the code you've attempted, the (wrong) results generated by your code and the (correct) expected results

I just showed you how to do 95% of this (i.e. everything except the trivial add "_B") in my answer to your previous question which you've apparently now deleted.

I just noticed your previous question was on SE, not here on SO.

If I understand correctly, this can be done simply in awk. If you have file.ind and it contains
    I001.HO M Ignore_Iran_Zoroastrian_PCA_outlier.HO
    I002.HO M Ignore_Iran_Zoroastrian_PCA_outlier.HO
    IREJ-T006.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T009.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T022.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T023.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T026.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T027.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T037.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T040.HO M Iran_Fars.HO

And, you have file2.txt that contains:
   IREJ-T026.HO
   IREJ-T027.HO
   IREJ-T037.HO
   IREJ-T040.HO

And, you want to append _B to all records in file.ind with a first field that matches a record in file2.txt, you can do something similar to:
awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1]++; next } {if ($1 in a) { $0=$0 "_B" }; print}' file2.txt file.ind

How it Works
awk reads each file record-by-record (line-by-line) and it applies each rule [condition] { rule } to each record in the order you write each rule. Above you have two-rules:

FNR == NR { a[$1]++; next } which says for the first file (FNR file record number == NR total number of records) -- so 1st file (file2.txt in example), simply stores the fields in the file as indexes to an array a and skips to the next record,
{if ($1 in a) { $0=$0 "_B" }; print} now reading the file.ind (2nd file in example), if the first field of the record in file.ind matches any index of the array a, then add a _B to the record, print the record.

So you read all the records from file2.txt as indexes in the array a and if the array index matches the beginning of any record in file.ind you append a _B.
Simply redirect the output to a newfile to save the results, e.g. awk ... file2.txt file.ind > newfile.ind
Example Use/Output
$ awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1]++; next } {if ($1 in a) { $0=$0 "_B" }; print}' file2.txt file.ind
    I001.HO M Ignore_Iran_Zoroastrian_PCA_outlier.HO
    I002.HO M Ignore_Iran_Zoroastrian_PCA_outlier.HO
    IREJ-T006.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T009.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T022.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T023.HO M Iran_Fars.HO
    IREJ-T026.HO M Iran_Fars.HO_B
    IREJ-T027.HO M Iran_Fars.HO_B
    IREJ-T037.HO M Iran_Fars.HO_B
    IREJ-T040.HO M Iran_Fars.HO_B

Let me know if that isn't what you are asking. I'm happy to help further. I'll edit and fill in how it works as well.

This is perfect thank you! It has really illustrated for me the power of awk and my need to learn it

If you are going to be working with Linux, then learning awk will save you 100 times the amount of time it takes to learn. The GNU Awk User's Guide is a great reference. It truly is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. It's syntax is similar to C, and it's quite simple. It just applies the rules you write in the order you write them to each line of text it reads. There is a special BEGIN rule that runs before the 1st record is processed and an END rule that runs at the end. That's it in a nutshell :)

And even working on windows, you have WSL or MSys2 which both provide a Linux command line with awk available. Both awk and sed (with it's little brother grep) give you a lot of text processing power. All support REGEX matching -- which itself is deep-magic for text processing. Have fun, and add those to your toolbox when you get a chance. There are good tutorials for all, but really, it's just using them over and over that helps cement the learning.

Use this Perl one-liner:
perl -lane 'BEGIN { %req = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } `cat required.txt`; } if ( $req{ $F[0] } ) { $F[2] .= "_B" } print join "\t", @F;' infile.ind > outfile.ind

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
-e : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
-n : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to $_ by default.
-l : Strip the input line separator ("\n" on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
-a : Split $_ into array @F on whitespace or on the regex specified in -F option.
BEGIN { ... } : Execute the code inside this block before executing any of the implicit loops specified by the -n or other options.
%req = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } `cat required.txt`; : Read the entire required.txt file into hash %req, where the keys are each line (with terminal newline removed), and the values are 1.
if ( $req{ $F[0] } ) { $F[2] .= "_B" }  : If the first field ($F[0]) was found in the %req hash, append _B to the third field ($F[2], or population).
print join "\t", @F; : Print all fields delimited by TAB.
See also:

perldoc perlrun: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches


I was curious and I tried with the files listed, and I don't get the _B appended anywhere. I do get tab separation of the original file. I'll have to digest the perl a bit, been many years since I was current.

@DavidC.Rankin Hmm... I tested it before posting, and got the "_B" appended correctly. Note that I assumed that the OP intended to have no leading or trailing whitespace in both input files (there is some now, and I assumed that this was a formatting artifact). So I did not remove any such whitespace in my code.

That's it. I left the leading whitespace in the file. That explains it.

Okay, removing the whitespace, now I get the _B for all records in the required.txt file except IREJ-T026.HO. Did you get the  _B appended to all matching records from required.txt? The game is afoot!

Thank you! I have never attempted to use Perl before, I will check out that link!

@DavidC.Rankin Yes, I double-checked again, and all records look ok, including the one you mentioned. I suspect that it is due to some whitespace lingering around.
